# jQuery - Cannot retrieve Input Number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```
<input id='nb' name="nb" type="number" placeholder="Number"/>
```

jQuery.val() returns the value if there are only numbers, but empty if there is any letter.

Chrome shows the input number arrows (and they work), but I can type letters too.. Weird thing

BTW on mozilla and IE8 it becomes a normal input text (guess I have an old mozilla)

Any idea ? Couldn't find anything on jQuery doc specific to number inputs with .val()

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `this.value` give (in place of `$(this).val()`)?

Comment: The most easy way to do this, in approach, is to ignore HTML5, use an `<input type="text"...` and set an `.onkeyup` function to accept only numbers (regex for example), because HTML5 it's not really supported by all.

Comment: Change type to text, you will get number as well as letters whatever you type

Comment: It's similar, but not duplicate. Here, OP is using HTML5. Duplicated will be if he worked as I suggested in a previous comment and his real problem is getting the value from the input.

Comment: If Chrome allows to input random letters as well, that’s a bug in my opinion – http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number) says, _“User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid floating-point number.”_

Comment: @DavidThomas -> undefined, always, even on text inputs. I believe that you can't use standard .value on jquery selectors

Comment: @CBroe -> In that case, is there anything wrong about my input ? There is not much I could have done wrong here

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX -> that's probably what I am going to do. Sad.

Comment: @user2316341 If you want, I can suggest you an answer.

Comment: _“I believe that you can't use standard .value on jquery selectors”_ – you can’t access normal DOM element properties on jQuery objects, because they aren’t DOM elements; you’d have to “de-reference” the jQuery object first to get to the real DOM element: `$("#nb")[0].value`

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for `input type="text"` instead HTML5 input `input type="number"`:

```
//HTML

<input id="inp" type="text" />

//JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY NEEDED)

function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    // SOME OPTIONS LIKE ENTER, BACKSPACE, HOME, END, ARROWS, ETC.
    var arrayExceptions = [8, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 27, 35, 36, 37,
        38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144];
    if ((evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57) &&
            (evt.keyCode < 96 || evt.keyCode > 106) && // NUMPAD
            $.inArray(evt.keyCode, arrayExceptions) === -1) {
        return false;
    }
}

$('#inp').on('keydown', onlyNumbers);

//JAVASCRIPT (WITHOUT JQUERY)

function inArray(value, arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (value === arr[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    // SOME OPTIONS LIKE ENTER, BACKSPACE, HOME, END, ARROWS, ETC.
    var arrayExceptions = [8, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 27, 35, 36, 37,
        38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144];
    if ((evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57) &&
            (evt.keyCode < 96 || evt.keyCode > 106) && // NUMPAD
              inArray(evt.keyCode, arrayExceptions) === -1) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('inp').onkeydown = onlyNumbers;
```

As I said in my comment, until HTML5 becomes an standard web language that we can work with it properly, I prefer to use this.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr5M6/)** with jQuery 
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a577p/)** without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only numbers from input then you need to use regular expressions. Initially get the value from input using $(your_element).val() then use regular expressions.

[Here](http://i.guibench.com/snippet/ag9zfmd1aWJlbmNoYWxwaGFyDwsSB1Byb2plY3QYuY4DDA) is a running example. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not my problem, I am already using this kind of solution to enable cross browser support. I hoped that on HTML5 capable browsers, this wouldn't be needed, but apparently even chrome doesn't always support "number" inputs.

Just for info, what I use http://jsfiddle.net/gJQCf/